# Solving the differential equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = (-0.5) \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R_0}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y+1) = f(x-2,y)$. I have two questions, both related.

1. Can we say that this is equivalent to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = (-0.5) \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$?
2. Is $f(x,y) = g(x-2y)$ always for some function $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$?

My hunch is that they both hold true always but I can't prove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to find examples that both statements are false. I would look at periodic functions in $x$ and $y$, or constants. Try for example $$f(x,y)=\sin(2\pi x)\sin(2\pi y)$$It obeys the initial condition (both sides are $f(x,y)$). An alternative that is easier to check for both questions is $$f(x,y)=\sin(2\pi y)$$

Comment: Right (and thanks!). What about the opposite direction? Can you give an example where the DE holds but not the $f(x,y+1) = f(x-2, y)$ equation?

Comment: There is a theorem in Differential Geometry that vector fields on differential manifolds are locally integrable.  You could say that  
 $v=1\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+.5\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial y} $   
is the vector field and apply Picard's Theorem (in some books).  An online paper is https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/SolODE.pdf