# How to solve $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = (-0.5) \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the following DE: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = (-0.5) \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ where $f: \mathbb{R_0^2} \to \mathbb{R}$.

How do I solve this? Since the differentials are partial, we can not re-arrange them and integrate like we do in high-school.

Note: Please don't tag [my other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375564/solving-the-differential-equation-frac-partial-f-partial-x-0-5-cdot) since the questions are essentially different.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Do you have any kind of initial condition (like a function $f_0(x)=f(x,0)$), or are you looking for a general solution?

Comment: @Arthur Not really. Ideally, I'm looking for a general solution but if that's too tedious or can not be computed, maybe then you can set $f(0,0) = 0$ (if that changes anything).

Comment: @MatthewH. No idea how that works.

Comment: Try separation of variables method. For example https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/SeparationofVariables.aspx

Comment: I meant to write $\big<1,1/2\big>\cdot \vec{\nabla}f=0$. This equation suggests the level sets of $f$ are always parallel to the vector $\big<1,1/2\big>$ which is only possible if $f(x,y)=g(x-2y)$ for some differentiable $g$. Are you familiar with the gradient and its relationship to the level sets of $f$?

Comment: It's just a transport equation. Solution method is called method of characteristics.

Comment: @MatthewH. Wow. If you see the post I tagged, you'd see that I had the hunch that the equation would be $g(x-2y)$ but couldn't figure it out. But no, I don't know really.. level sets, gradients and all that. I'll read that up. Thanks.

Comment: @Meowdog That's what I needed (I think). Thanks!

Comment: @tomtomtom you are welcome