# Is $f(x,y+1) = f(x-2,y) \iff \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$ where $f$ is weakly increasing?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a weakly increasing function such that $f(x,y+1) = f(x-2,y)$. Can we then say that this is equivalent to $$f(x,y+1) = f(x-2,y) ~ \forall ~ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \iff \frac{\partial f(r,s)}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial f(r,s)}{\partial y} = 0 ~ \forall ~ (r,s) \in \mathbb{R}^2$$?

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0 \implies f(x,y) = g(x-2y)$ (for some differentiable function $g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$). Then it is immediate that $f(x,y+1) = g(x-2y-2) = f(x-2,y)$. The converse doesn't seem to hold, but there's a connection between the two equations, so maybe they do and I can't figure out. The crux is the strict increasing nature of $f$ if that changes anything.

Note: This question arises from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375564/solving-the-differential-equation-frac-partial-f-partial-x-0-5-cdot) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375679/how-to-solve-frac-partial-f-partial-x-0-5-cdot-frac-partial-f-pa?noredirect=1&lq=1). I was given examples with periodic functions but not really non-periodic ones.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134023/discussion-on-question-by-tomtomtom-is-fx-y1-fx-2-y-iff-frac-partial).

Comment: Note to self/everyone who sees the post: If $f(x+1, y) = f(x, y+2)$, then would this eq. $\implies \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ assuming strict monotonicity?